# Windows: can't get flac.exe error messages into a file

Tags: windows, testing, output, flac

I need to test bunch of FLAC files and get all errors into a txt file. I used the following syntax which is very common and usually works fine with all programs:

c:\temp\FLAC\flac.exe -t myflacfile.flac >> c:\temp\report.txt

But it surprisingly doesn't work! No idea why error messages can't be catched. The report file gots created though. Please share your thoughts, cause' I haven't find a word on the Net about it.

Comment: Every command line process has one input stream (`stdin`) and *two* output streams (`stdout` and `stderr`). You're redirecting `stdout` but not `stderr`. See [Redirecting error messages from command prompt: STDERR/STDOUT](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/110930)

Comment: It doesn't catch OK messages either, not only error messages. I tried 2>> c:\temp\report.txt syntax, it didn't work as well. Seems there's something wrong with flac.exe

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in syntax. There is extra space in command line before an output filename. Commands like

```
flac.exe -t 1.flac 2>>a.txt
```

or

```
flac.exe -t 1.flac 2>a.txt
```

are working well.

Comment: Thanks for that. it's the `2` that does it before the `>>`. I must research what that does now.